# Difference between Mouth Vowels& Throat Vowels, and do mouth vowels cause damage, and why?

Tags: voice

In an article about causes of vocal damage, the author lists the use of **mouth vowels** instead of **throat vowels** as one of the causes of vocal damage.

Would anyone be able top explain the difference between the two, & what would be the reason that mouth vowels are damaging?

article link:
[https://voiceteacher.com/damaging.html#:~:text=Use%20of%20mouth%20vowels%20instead%20of%20pharyngeal%20vowels](https://voiceteacher.com/damaging.html#:%7E:text=Use%20of%20mouth%20vowels%20instead%20of%20pharyngeal%20vowels)

Comment: I wouldn't put too much stock in this source; it seems to make a lot of statements as fact that might in fact be preference or anecdotal experience, often simply by sticking the word "healthy" onto its opinion-statement, and doesn't always offer medical explanation or support. I lost trust when he said singing without vibrato hurts your voice.

Comment: Still, is his point about mouth vowels correct, to your knowledge?

Comment: I'll have to let others speak to it. I had to Google "pharyngeal vowels"; https://sail.usc.edu/~lgoldste/General_Phonetics/Vowels/Vowel_Theories.html seems to shed some light on it...